# What the shortcut to jump to a link when theres an error in debug console?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If i press F8 it does not jump to the line shown above:

[image]

Only goes to the line if i ctrl+click the message.Is possible to set a shortcut to this action?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>F8</kbd> should work when you have `editorFocus` - that is the default keybinding.  If your focus is already in the problem view you can make this keybinding (in `keybindings.json`):

```
  {
    "key": "f8",        // or whatever keys you want
    "command": "editor.action.marker.next",
    "when": "problemFocus"
  }
```

Comment: It doesn't go to the line even with focus in the editor